# Updating multiple rows from ids array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array like so:

```
Array ( [0] => 6599 [1] => 6600 )
```

This array, will be much larger in a live scenario.

I need to update my database table rows which have the `entry_id`(s) in this array, updating just one column `status`, with the value `open`.

I had thought I could use `update_batch` (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#update, but I couldn't get it to work.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use where_in method

```
$ids = Array(12,34,55,677,123);
$this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
$this->db->update('table', array('status' => 'open'));
```